# Convert website to windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8

I installed Visual Studio Express 2013.

I also have a local server installed(I used UniformServer) with a little php website.

I opened Visual Studio Express. I created a new project Templates/JavaScript/Blank App

**How can I convert the site from localhost to the new Windows 8 app?**

In the file package.appxmanifest, replacing `default.html` with `http://localhost` in "Start page" field, doesn't work.

Comment: You can't run PHP in a Windows 8 app.

Comment: But There must be a way to read in a windows 8 app content from a website.

Comment: That's not how Windows Store apps work.  Are you asking how to send an AJAX request?

Comment: Yes, Ajax request! Is what I'm looking for.